# How to launch Windows Scheduler by command-line?

Tags: windows, command-line, scheduler

I mean to open the built-in Windows GUI from command line- not to launch by Schtasks

Comment: Perhaps move this question to superuser.com instead of closing? This is a useful question with valid answers.

Comment: Needs moved to superuser

Comment: Yet another useful question with a good answer closed. :(

Answer (score 73):

**`taskschd.msc` is available in Windows Vista and later.**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871.aspx

I could have sworn I'd seen a little task scheduler GUI like you're talking about prior to Vista, but maybe I was thinking of the "Add Scheduled Task" wizard.

You might have to settle for opening the scheduled tasks explorer with this command:

```
control schedtasks
```

I couldn't find any way to launch the "Add Scheduled Task" wizard from the command line, unfortunately (there has to be a way!)

Comment: Works on Win 7 as well.

Comment: @Nenotlep, Win 8.1 too.

Comment: @Andy, For pre-Vista, Shouldn't there be some way to run `mmc` and feed it the task scheduler as input?

Comment: Works also on Windows Server 2016, so I guess also on most previous and future versions :-)

Answer (score 45):

I'm using Windows 2003 on the server. I'm in action with "SCHTASKS.EXE"

```
    SCHTASKS /parameter [arguments]

    Description:
        Enables an administrator to create, delete, query, change, run and
        end scheduled tasks on a local or remote system. Replaces AT.exe.

    Parameter List:
        /Create         Creates a new scheduled task.

        /Delete         Deletes the scheduled task(s).

        /Query          Displays all scheduled tasks.

        /Change         Changes the properties of scheduled task.

        /Run            Runs the scheduled task immediately.

        /End            Stops the currently running scheduled task.

        /?              Displays this help message.

    Examples:
        SCHTASKS
        SCHTASKS /?
        SCHTASKS /Run /?
        SCHTASKS /End /?
        SCHTASKS /Create /?
        SCHTASKS /Delete /?
        SCHTASKS /Query  /?
        SCHTASKS /Change /?

    ┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
    │ Executed Wed 02/29/2012 10:48:36.65 │
    └─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

It's quite interesting and makes me feel so powerful. :)

Comment: +1 for: "It's quite interesting and makes me feel so powerful. :)"

Comment: great answer. just provide one more linke from microsoft
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx#BKMK_create

Answer (score 25):

This launches the Scheduled Tasks MMC Control Panel:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\taskschd.msc /s
```

Older versions of windows had a splash screen for the MMC control panel and the /s switch would supress it.  It's not needed but doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Are you sure? I can't find it. I'm using Win XP SP2

Comment: What is the `/s` switch for? It works even without it.

Comment: MMC used to have a splash screen, and the /s switch would suppress it.  Wow, these answers are making me feel old.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: People here are mostly looking for running command version of the scheduler but looking at the question that is asking for the command to run the GUI, this is the correct answer.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi, Doesn't seem to work on pre-Vista......

Comment: @Pacerier update the answer if you find a solution :)  I don't have an ancient image to test with

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the GUI is available in XP.  I can get the list of scheduled tasks (but not the GUI) to open with the following command,

```
control.exe  schedtasks
```

Then you can use the wizard to add a new scheduled task, for example.

In XP, you can find the Scheduler GUI from within Windows Help if you search for "Scheduled Tasks" then click on "Step by Step instructions" and open the scheduler GUI.  Clicking on the last link executes the following command, which likely could be translatedinto something that would open the Scheduler GUI from the command line.  Does anyone know how?

```
ms-its:C:\WINDOWS\Help\mstask.chm::/EXEC=,control.exe, schedtasks CHM=ntshared.chm FILE=alt_url_windows_component.htm
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example I just used:

```
at 8am /EVERY:M,T,W,Th,F,S,Su cmd /c c:\myapp.exe
```

The result was:

```
Added a new job with job ID = 1
```

Then, to check my work:

```
at
```

Answer (score 6):

You might want to have look at simple command line scheduler "at":

---

```
C:\Documents and Settings\mahendra.patil>at/?
```

The AT command schedules commands and programs to run on a computer at
a specified time and date. The Schedule service must be running to use
the AT command.

```
AT [\\computername] [ [id] [/DELETE] | /DELETE [/YES]]
AT [\\computername] time [/INTERACTIVE]
    [ /EVERY:date[,...] | /NEXT:date[,...]] "command"
```

\computername     Specifies a remote computer. Commands are scheduled on the
                   local computer if this parameter is omitted.

id                 Is an identification number assigned to a scheduled
                   command.

/delete            Cancels a scheduled command. If id is omitted, all the
                   scheduled commands on the computer are canceled.

/yes               Used with cancel all jobs command when no further
                   confirmation is desired.

time               Specifies the time when command is to run.

/interactive       Allows the job to interact with the desktop of the user
                   who is logged on at the time the job runs.

/every:date[,...]  Runs the command on each specified day(s) of the week or
                   month. If date is omitted, the current day of the month
                   is assumed.

/next:date[,...]   Runs the specified command on the next occurrence of the
                   day (for example, next Thursday).  If date is omitted, the
                   current day of the month is assumed.

"command"          Is the Windows NT command, or batch program to be run.

Comment: I realize this answer goes back to 2008, so it was probably valid then.  If you run `at` now in a recent version of Windows you'll get this error back: "The AT command has been deprecated. Please use schtasks.exe instead"

Answer (score 6):

You can make a new shortcut to:

```
control schedtasks
```

Name it something easy like "tsks.lnk" and then save it in c:\windows\system32.

You can now press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then type "tsks" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and voila.  No mouse necessary at that point.
Or in Windows Vista/7/2008, just press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>, then type "tsks" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

You can use either `TASKSCHD.MSC` or `CONTROL SCHEDTASKS`

[Here](http://am-techzone.blogspot.com/2011/07/windows-shortcuts.html) are some more such commands.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also running XP SP2, and this works perfectly (from the command line...):

```
start control schedtasks
```

Comment: **NOTE:** this does exactly what you asked for: "_open the built-in Windows GUI from command line_."

Answer (score -3):

If you’re asking what I think you’re asking, you can open it by executing this:

```
explorer.exe "C:\WINDOWS\Tasks\"
```

Comment: Don't forget "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks". Your answer only gives a subset of the jobs.